# Symfony REST API Date format

Tags: php, rest, symfony, date

How would you suggest passing from the backend (DateTime format) to a Js frontend (and vice versa) a "date" using Symfony?

At the moment I created (other than the ORM field "date") a "formattedDate" getter that returns the date formatted as required by the client (it could be a timestamp or a simple date formatted with a locale e.g. yyyy-mm-dd).
The client then reads the "formattedDate" and sends it back modified, so on every "update" action I parse the json and if I received a "formattedDate" field I use it to write the "date" field.

I'm not sure this is a good approach since it's requiring me (in my opinion) too many tweaks to get it working and I'm pretty sure there is something easier that I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: The easiest and most flexible way would be using ISO 8601, since both (PHP and JS) understand exactly what it tells. `date('now', 'c');`. Symfony (and Doctrine) will easily understand the date format, too!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many approaches that could work and the one you are already using is ok.

The way I work with dates in Symfony projects is by using the DateTimeImmutable class; So I agree with the FrontEnd on what format they need the dates and anytime I send a date to FrontEnd I will format it accordingly and anytime I got back a date from FrontEnd I will be transforming it to be a DateTimeImmutable.

You can find more about DateTimeImmutable on the official [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php)

I hope this gives you a better perspective.